# Сворачивание модального окна вместе с родительским

Tags: c#, winforms, многопоточность

Есть родительская форма. Из нее вызывается методом ShowDialog еще одно, в котором выполняется какая-либо длительная операция. Для отображения процента выполнения использую ProgressBar, значение которого изменяется через делегат в стороннем потоке через Invoke. Когда просто пытаюсь свернуть оба окна через WindowState, то программа падает с исключением на вызове делегата изменения значения ProgressBar'a. Подскажите что делаю не так? Спасибо.

```
        // Функция рабочего потока
        private void ThreadDo()
        {
            dSetParam incProgress = new dSetParam(IncProgress); // Увелечение значения прогресса
            try
            {
                // Что-то делаем
                foreach (...)
                {
                    ...
                    this.Invoke(incProgress, 1);
                }
                dialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK;
            }
            catch (ThreadAbortException)
            {
                // Выполнение потока было отменено
                dialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Abort;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Ошибка чтения файла", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                dialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Abort;
            }
            finally
            {
                // Завершаем выполнение
                dComplete complete = new dComplete(Complete);
                this.Invoke(complete, dialogResult);
            }
        }

        private void IncProgress(int increment)
        {
            progressBar.Value += increment;
        }

        private void Complete(DialogResult dialogResult)
        {
            this.DialogResult = dialogResult;
        }

        private void btnMinimize_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
           this.Owner.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
        }
```

Почему падает я понял - почему то при минимизации родительского окна, мдальное окно возвращает DialogResult и, по сути, закрывается, а поток все еще выполняется. А вот почему так происхдит не пойму. Вот текст исключения:

```
Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created.
```

Answer (score 1):

Если это действительно связано с Dialog, то чтобы долго не возиться предлагаю сделать следующим образом: создать форму, но не вызывать ее через ShowDialog, а просто Show() и сделать если нужно родительскую форму в Enabled = false. Тогда при сворачивании оно не будет реагировать и закрываться. (По идее это сделано для обеспечения безопасности, чтобы диалоги не могли висеть в таком (Minimized) состоянии).

Comment: Ну так я подобное сразу и сделал. Но хотелось бы понять почему окно все-таки закрывается.

Comment: В отличие от линуксов, здесь есть хоть какие-то стандарты и правила, которые, кстати, все же помагают правильно создавать приложения) Так что мне даже приятно, что оно **так** реагирует